# Network Trailers Add and Monitor

Tags: networking

Odd question I know; I need to assert a one byte Trailer in all frames leaving my workstation and remove a one byte trailer from all frames entering the workstation.
Why I hear you cry; Well the workstation is simulating part of a switch device and the silicon it's connected to communicates it's ingress port by setting the Trailers accordingly.

The Egress Trailer needs to be 0x00, while ingress can be thrown away.

Any ideas where to start looking.

Regards Steve

Comment: There is software (e.g. [here](https://packetsender.com/)) that allows you to send and receive arbitrary packets. Is that what you need?

Comment: Hi Jos. Yes got a version that does that, however it only allows you to change the payload rather than setting the trailers themselves. What i would like is for all traffic to have the trailers either fixed or controllable for egress and monitored or displayed for ingress. Normally this only happens within a switch although there appears to be a management protocol that uses it for external communication, for port numbering and time messages.